# ASP.NET Web API 2 How to clear the exception to prevent being logged twice by Application Insights

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights

I installed Application Insights into my ASP.NET Web API application.
I added global exception handler to log specific exception as a custom events to App Insights:

```
public class AppExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
    private readonly IAuthEventLogger _authEventLogger;

    public AppExceptionHandler()
    {
        _authEventLogger = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IAuthEventLogger>();
    }

    public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        Exception ex = context.Exception;
        IHttpActionResult newResult = null;

        while (ex != null)
        {
            if (ex is AppSessionException)
            {
                newResult = new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, context.Request);
                _authEventLogger.TrackUnauthorizedRequestEvent(context.Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery);

                break;
            }      
        }

        if (newResult != null)
        {
            context.Result = newResult;
        }
        else
        {
            base.Handle(context);
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine, But now all the exceptions are logged twice: in addition to custom events that my logger writes to, exceptions are also logged automatically in the "Failures" App Insights section.

Is there a way to not log automatically my custom exceptions as "Failures" and log all others?
I tried to clear `ExceptionHandlerContext.Exception` property but it is a readonly.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MS-DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-exceptions#web-api) of Azure monitor WEB API exception concept, if you are using the Custom Handler to track exception you can remove it to prevent double tracking exception.

> Few cases cannot handle by exception filter which follows:
>
> - Exceptions thrown from controller constructors.
> - Exceptions thrown from message handlers.
> - Exceptions thrown during routing.
> - Exceptions thrown during response content serialization.
> - Exception thrown during application startup.
> - Exception thrown in background tasks.

To avoid double tracking of your exception you can use the custom handling logging to avoid it.

I have created one **WEB API** and added in handling the exception logging with dedicated. I can be able to see only one occurrence in an application Insights.

```cs
namespace Webapicustomlogging.Log
{
    public class AiExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
    {
    // Use the specific context to logging 
        public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
        {
            if (context != null && context.Exception != null)
            {
                var aiTrackClient = new TelemetryClient();
                aiTrackClient.TrackException(context.Exception);
            }
            base.Log(context);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: doesn't work for me. I tried your suggestion and see my exception twice (Both in Failures and Exceptions)

Comment: could you set `<customErrors mode="On">` in your web.config and re-check your scenario?

Comment: I tried with **customErrors mode** has **ON** the error cannot duplicate in failure.